# How can I drag files from Explorer to Liquid XML Studio?

Tags: liquid-xml

When I drag a file onto Liquid XML a deny icon appears, how can I drag files from Explorer to Liquid XML Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging files from Windows Explorer is valid but you can not drop them on an existing editor, drop them on the menu/toolbar/Title Bar section of Liquid XML Studio window.

Basically you cannot drop them onto documents that are already open.

If you drop them on an open document window they are seen as targets for that window and are dealt by the window, which may not allow files to be dropped on it.